# ActionMailer Error in Redmine Plugin

Tags: actionmailer, redmine, redmine-plugins

I have the following mailing code in app/models.

```
class Mailman < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => "xyz"
  # Sends an Email reminder to all the users who missed a pickup date
  def check_out_reminder(reservation)
    recipient = reservation.user.mail
    subject   = "Checkout Reminder for '#{reservation.bookable.name}'."
    mail(:to => recipient, :subject => subject)
  end

  def check_in_reminder(reservation)
    recipient = reservation.user.mail
    subject   = "Checkin Reminder for '#{reservation.bookable.name}'."
    mail(:to => recipient, :subject => subject)
  end

end
```

I have test code in test/unit which goes as:

```
require File.expand_path('../../test_helper', __FILE__)

class MailmanTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  fixtures :reservations

  def test_check_out_reminder
    reservation = Reservation.first 
    # Send the email, then test that it got queued
    Mailman.check_out_reminder(reservation).deliver
    assert !ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?
  end

end
```

The test on execution however gives an error:

```
test_check_out_reminder(MailmanTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `mail' for nil:NilClass
    /Users/myth/Learn/Code/redmine/plugins/redmine_asset_tracker/app/models/mailman.rb:9:in `check_out_reminder'
    /Users/myth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
    /Users/myth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
    /Users/myth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
    /Users/myth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionmailer-3.2.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:456:in `process'
    /Users/myth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionmailer-3.2.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:451:in `initialize'
    /Users/myth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionmailer-3.2.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:438:in `new'
    /Users/myth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionmailer-3.2.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:438:in `method_missing'
    /Users/myth/Learn/Code/redmine/plugins/redmine_asset_tracker/test/unit/mailer_test.rb:9:in `test_check_out_reminder'
    /Users/myth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mocha-0.11.4/lib/mocha/integration/mini_test/version_230_to_262.rb:28:in `run'
```

Why is the mail method not being recognized even when I am inheriting the right class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a missing fixture. 
The line `recipient = reservation.user.mail` was causing the error and not the Action Mailer's `mail(:to => recipient, :subject => subject)`

Comment: How'd you find it was a fixture problem?  Also, accept your own answer so people know it's been solved. :)